# How can I declare a double line variable in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I wanted to have a variable that takes in gradient **with a fallback** in SASS. How can I achieve this?

Code I want as a single variable:

```css
#4568DC;
-webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, #4568DC);
linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, #4568DC);
```

In other words, how can I declare three properties in one variable such that when it compiles, it turns into three properties. So an input like this:

```css
background: $combined-variable
```

Should give an output like this:

```css
background: #4568DC;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, #4568DC);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, #4568DC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to solve the problem via a single variable with a textual substituion. Instead, take a look at [sass mixins](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-sass-mixins), cause they provide exactly the behaviour you want. You could use them like:

```
@mixin gradient($color) {
    background: $color;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, $color);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #B06AB3, $color);
}

.my-rule {
    display: inline;
    @include gradient(#4568DC);
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted to use it to customize bootstrap sass and I wanted the primary color to be a gradient. So the primary will be a webkit and linear gradient with a fallback color. So the primary is not actually one hex value, but 3 values of which 2 are gradient and 1 fallback. How can I do that?

Comment: You could just remove the `background: $color` line no?

Comment: Parth Agarwal, you can create mixin with 3 parameters: `@mixin gradient($color-spot-1, $color-spot-2, $fallback-color)`.

Comment: @HoriaComan, I can't remove the background: $color line. I want the primary color to be a gradient. When I set the primary color to a gradient, it doesn't work because sass uses darken, etc in later stages. I get an error saying cannot use darken since primary is not a color (it's a gradient)